# jquery confirm box not working second page in pagination

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I have to show number of users in table in a table with pagination
And I have delete option for each user
Im using datatable pagination
It has to ask confirm before delete the user, So im using jquery .confirm
function (jquer.confirm.js)
This jquery confirm box not working in second page of pagination.

Here is my code:

```
$(".del_user").each(function(){
   var user_id = this.id;
   $("#"+user_id).confirm({
   text: "Are you sure you want to delete this user?",
    title: "Confirmation required",
    confirm: function(button) {
   <!---delete function()---->
    return false; 
    },
    cancel: function(button) {
    // nothing to do
    },
   confirmButton: "Yes",
   cancelButton: "No",
   post: true,
   confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
   cancelButtonClass: "btn-default"
    });
});
```

How to solve this?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Im not getting any error. but confirm box not show up in second page

Comment: post your html, if possible create fiddle

Comment: Use jQuery(document).delegate() or 
jQuery(document).live() method for that

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

your jquery dom not loading for another tab so my experience is doing following like that

```
".paginate_button" is your tab button class name

 $(".paginate_button").click(function(){
$(".del_user").each(function(){
   var user_id = this.id;
   $("#"+user_id).confirm({
   text: "Are you sure you want to delete this user?",
    title: "Confirmation required",
    confirm: function(button) {
   <!---delete function()---->
    return false; 
    },
    cancel: function(button) {
    // nothing to do
    },
   confirmButton: "Yes",
   cancelButton: "No",
   post: true,
   confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
   cancelButtonClass: "btn-default"
    });
});
});
```

Comment: its not checkbox. im just using a href : <a href="" class="del_user" id="id of user"><i class='fa fa-remove'></i></a>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

add "fnDrawCallback" option in your datatable function:

```
$('#datable_id').dataTable({
      "fnDrawCallback": function () {
            createconfirmationbox();
      },
});
```

And your jquery confirmation function look like this :

```
function createconfirmationbox(){
$('.someclass').confirmation({
    onConfirm: function () {

      *do something on confirmation*  

    }
});}
```